# Sorting NSFetchedResultsController based on which relationship it belongs to

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor

Sort descriptors with custom blocks are not supported in iOS6, so I need to figure out another way to do this:

A Student entity can belong to one of two sets: `confirmedClasses` or `pendingClasses`. I want to fetch Students with the following predicate:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY confirmedClasses.classId== %@
    OR ANY pendingClasses.classId == %@", currentClass.classId, currentClass.classId]];
```

So a user can be either as a confirmed student in the class or a pending student. What I want is to sort the results so that all confirmed students are listed first, and pending students are listed after all confirmed students.

Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just use two predicates, compound for fetch, and use to filter results:

```
NSPredicate *confirmed = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY confirmedClasses.classId== %@,currentClass.classId];

NSPredicate *pending = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY pendingClasses.classId== %@,currentClass.classId];

NSArray *predicates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:confirmed,pending,nil];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates]];

//Perform fetch into an array called 'results'

NSArray *filteredConfirmed = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:confirmed];
NSArray *filteredPending = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pending];

NSArray *sortedResult = [filteredConfirmed arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:filteredPending];
```

Comment: Well the thing is that I'm using a fetched results controller, and that can only be sorted pre-fetch, or else this would work..

Comment: Maybe you can make the predicates a property of the class that's using the FRC. Then you can use the compound predicate on the FRC, and filter the FRC's objects when the data changes. Then just use the `sortedResult` as your data source?

Comment: You may also want to consider adding an attribute to your "Class" managedObject to indicate whether it is pending or current. Then you can sort on that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do two separate fetches? That way you'll have all the confirmed students in one array, and all the pending students in another. It'll be easier to catenate the two groups in the order you want than to retrieve them all and then sort them according to status.